# Run a shell script from Spotlight?

Tags: macos, mac, spotlight

I wrote a very basic script that launches "bc" in quiet mode very a simple but effective calculator. I want to be able to launch it via Spotlight. I can make it a ".command" file, but it never shows up under "top hits". I've tried turning it into an application via Platypus, but it's not designed for an interactive window. Does anyone have any other thoughts to make this work?

Goal - run bc via spotlight with as few keys as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save a script like this as an application in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "clear;printf '\\e[3J';bc -ql"
    activate
end tell
```

`printf '\\e[3J'` clears the scrollback.

If you use iTerm, you can create a profile for bc:

[image]

Then run an AppleScript like this:

```
tell application "iTerm" to tell (make new terminal) to launch session "bc"
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution. One question - when I "quit" BC i am returned to the terminal, is there an option I can pass via AppleScript to quit terminal after BC quits?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out:  
      do script "clear;printf '\\e[3J';bc -ql;exit"  
Thanks again